# Limiting access to Newsstand and Currents

Tags: android, ipad, newsstand-kit

I am creating magazines that will be used on iPad Newsstand and Google Currents, but I want to limit access to people who are members of my organization. Is it possible to publish to these venues, but not have public links?...rather, have hidden links that I can send to my members?

Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Check out Apple documentation (NKIssue, NKLibrary, NKAssetDownload etc). Here is a link to a nice tutorial

http://www.viggiosoft.com/blog/blog/2011/10/17/ios-newsstand-tutorial

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.